# Special deck pair probability

Tags: probability

I have a card deck having total $110$ cards. The deck has ten 10s, ten A's, ten J's, ten Q's, ten K's. How to compute the probability that if I turn five cards, I got at least one pair of 10, A, J, Q, or K?

Comment: Often, the best way to calculate 'at least one' is to calculate the probability of 'none', and then calculate 1-p.

Comment: What are the other $60$ cards then?

Comment: I think it does not matter what are the rest 60 cards. They are not 10, A, J, Q or K.

Comment: You're right, I just wanted to make sure that you got all the numbers correctly.

Comment: @barakmanos, Have you dealt with three of a kind?

Comment: @Michael: In the comment above no, in the answer below yes :)

Comment: My answer below (which you have accepted) is wrong. See the comment to it made by @awkward. Please un-accept it so I can delete it, and so that your question will be "reopened" for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

No court pair is the same as 0-5 singleton court cards.
$${60\choose 5}+{5\choose1}10{60\choose4}+{5\choose2}10^2{60\choose3}+...$$

Comment: Maybe it's worth noting that this results in a probability of about 0.3066 of getting at least one pair, since this answer disagrees with that of Barak Manos.  As a cross-check, I wrote a Monte Carlo simulation resulting in 306,500 successes in 10^6 hands, which is close agreement with your result.